# How to set up Gnash and Epiphany for youtube?

Tags: flash, plugins, youtube, epiphany, gnash

I like the browser Epiphany (now Web or something).

I also hate Flash and I heard about Gnash, its free alternative.

All I want to do is to set up Epiphany somehow to use Gnash on YouTube. I can't get that to work.

I have installed `browser-plugin-gnash`, but it doesn't do anything. I have plug-ins enabled in Epiphany. All it does is just display black box instead of video (just as if no plugin was installed).

Comment: (the reason why I don't just "suck it up" and just install flash is that it doesn't work properly in Epiphany either, and eats tons of my memory and CPU)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like it's possible.

When I go to the GNash website and actually look at the example video that is supposed to be working, I don't see anything, but I hear the sound. That means the Gnash is somehow, maybe, working.

But not on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to install ffmpeg.

`you@yourbox:~$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Comment: Nope, still out of luck.

What I decided to do is to just open the youtube links in VLC, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 12.04, and Epiphany plays Youtube videos using Gnash. I also have browser-plugin-gnash installed. I tried guessing which package I have that makes the difference (unless it's just something that was fixed in 12.04) and these are my candidates:

gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg - as @Jim suggested

chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra - in case Epiphany uses them too

libquvi7 - from the package description : "Library to parse Adobe flash video download links. It supports Youtube and other similar video websites."

Maybe one of them will do the trick.